# How to show custom input area with InputMethodService

Tags: android, ime

I'm developing a keyboard app based on using [InputMethodService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService#candidates-view). One of the tasks is to have a possibility to overlay an input area with a custom one in order to display additional icons to the left/right of the input area, use different colors for some text parts, etc. 
 
One of the workarounds for this is to use "Draw over other apps" possibility, but it requires [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission.
 
 
Is there any other way for InputMethodService to overlay the input area with some custom view?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to do is to create a custom view for your keyboard with not just the 'letter-keys' is that right?

Comment: @flide Yes, the idea behind it is to show an input area with additional formatting possibilities and features as a part of the keyboard. The user would be able to show/hide that custom input area, on its hiding the typed text would be committed to the original input area using `InputConnection`. 
Showing two input areas at once might confuse the user, so I'd like to cover the origin input area with the custom one when the user enables that custom input area.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first thing : I don't think it is possible for the IME to overlay the input area because every time you increase the size of your ime, the size of the application containing the input area will be shrunk in order to keep it on screen.

But I think what you are trying to achieve is possible. I believe the best way to provide the feature you want is the "[IME Fullscreen Mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService#FullscreenMode)". Once you have decided that the user needs more space to work with or the IME needs to do more than just react to the user input, fire up the full-screen mode and provide all the additional icons to your heart's content. The only down side of going this route will be that you ime will not only hide the "original" input area but also the whole application which contained that input area for the duration of the editing.